# Still cant watch dvd

Tags: dvd

I have followed all the instructions and installed the codex suggested libdvdread3 and 4 but cant install the libdvdcss and thus still cant watch any dvd

to specify it tells me that
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
can not be found but libdvdread4 has been installed

Comment: Is there a file `install-css.sh` at the path /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh? Also, on a general note: Assume that the people that will try and answer your question does not have any more background then what is stated in your question. For example, what instructions have you followed?

Comment: How do you try it? Did you try for example running vlc, and pressing `Media→Open Disk` ?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs This is what you need to know/do and all you need to know/do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the contents of */usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css*

> ### Content Scramble System (CSS)
>
> Many DVDs use CSS[0] as a form of a Digital Rights Management (DRM) to
>   encrypt the content of Video DVDs. To play such discs a special
>   library is needed to decode them, libdvdcss.
>
> Due to the legal limbo of libdvdcss in some particular juristictions,
>   some distributions including Debian do not distribute libdvdcss.
>
> If it is legal for you to use CSS in your juristiction, you can:
>
> - Manually download and compile the source code from
>     http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html.
> - Use packages from derivatives that include libdvdcss.
>
>   [0] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System
>
>   -- Daniel Baumann   Fri, 02 Oct 2009 16:10:06
>     +0200

So we need other solution.

Try to install other packages with

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, Install VLC media player. It plays most codecs without codec packs installed. This can be done through the Ubuntu software center or the command line:

sudo apt-get install vlc